# Windows 10 Mail giving me large TD cells

Tags: html, email

I am writing an email which is only having issues in "Windows 10 Mail." I have a 3 table cell with a graphic in the middle TD. The left & right TDs contain a 2-pixel height table with a gray background. This is to make it look like the icon is surrounded by 2 gray lines.

The small tables all have `height=2` applied. I've tried using VML code, no effect. Any ideas?

Results:

[image: Desired Result] [image: Windows 10 Mail Result]

Code below:

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="300" style="max-width: 300px">
 <tr>
  <td valign="middle" width="35%" style="max-width: 108px; line-height: 0; font-size: 0">
   <!-- Left Gray Table -->
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" style="max-width: 108px; max-height: 2px" height="2">
      <tr>
        <td height="2" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="height: 2px; background-color: #eaeaea; font-size: 0; line-height: 0"><img src="http://go.rocketlawyer.com/rs/148-CGS-511/images/spacer.gif" height="2" width="100%" style="min-width: 74px; max-width: 108px; min-height: 2px; max-height: 2px; display: block">
        </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
   <!-- END Left Gray Table -->
  </td>
  <td align="center" valign="middle" width="53" class="full-width-image" height="92"><img src="http://go.rocketlawyer.com/rs/148-CGS-511/images/icon-quick-answers.png" alt="Chat bubble icon" width="106" height="92" style="border-width:0;display:block;width:100%;max-width:53px;height:auto; max-height:92px">
  </td>
  <td valign="middle" width="35%" style="max-width: 108px;">
   <!-- RIGHT Gray Table -->
   <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" style="max-width: 108px; min-height: 2px; max-height: 2px" height="2">
    <tr>
     <td height="2" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="height: 2px; background-color: #eaeaea; font-size: 0; line-height: 0"><img src="http://go.rocketlawyer.com/rs/148-CGS-511/images/spacer.gif" height="2" width="100%" style="min-width: 74px; max-width: 108px; min-height: 2px; max-height: 2px; display: block">
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
   <!-- END RIGHT Gray Table -->
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the email client is making the height too high for the columns. Give this method a try to see how it goes.

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="300" style="max-width: 300px">
 <tr>
  <td valign="middle" width="35%" style="max-width: 108px; ">
   <!-- Left Gray Table -->
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/T24O6.png" height="2" width="100%" style="min-width: 74px; max-width: 108px; min-height: 2px; max-height: 2px; display: block">
   <!-- END Left Gray Table -->
  </td>
  <td align="center" valign="middle" width="53" class="full-width-image" height="92"><img src="http://go.rocketlawyer.com/rs/148-CGS-511/images/icon-quick-answers.png" alt="Chat bubble icon" width="106" height="92" style="border-width:0;display:block;width:100%;max-width:53px;height:auto; max-height:92px">
  </td>
  <td valign="middle" width="35%" style="max-width: 108px;">
   <!-- RIGHT Gray Table -->
   <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/T24O6.png" height="2" width="100%" style="min-width: 74px; max-width: 108px; min-height: 2px; max-height: 2px; display: block">
   <!-- END RIGHT Gray Table -->
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Tested in Outlook as well. What i have done is added a grey image with 1px height.

Hope this is what you were after.